# Questions on supremum

Tags: tag-removed, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Is it true that $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\frac{\left|\left(1+s\right)+tx\right|+\left|\left(1+t\right)x+s\right|}{1+\left|x\right|+\left|s+tx\right|}\geq1$$
for all $s,t\in\mathbb{R}$? Is it also true that $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\frac{\left|\left(1+s\right)x+t\right|+\left|\left(1+t\right)+sx\right|}{1+\left|x\right|+\left|sx+t\right|}\geq1 \ ?$$
Any answer to either of the two questions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There are troubles with the maximum: it may not exist at all! Take $s=-1$, $t=0$ in the 1st relation; the expression under max is $|x-1|/(2+|x|)$ which is strictly less than 1 for any $x\in\mathbb R$,
but the supremum is 1. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Wadim, thank you for pointing out. They should be "sup" instead of "max".

Comment: I've removed the "functional analysis" tag and added "inequalities".

Answer (score 6):

If I denote
$$
f(s,t;x)=\frac{\left|\left(1+s\right)+tx\right|+\left|\left(1+t\right)x+s\right|}{1+\left|x\right|+\left|s+tx\right|},
$$
then for $t\ne0$
$$
f\left(s,t;-\frac{s}{t}\right)=\frac{1+|s/t|}{1+|s/t|}=1,
$$
hence the supremum over all $x\in\mathbb R$ is at least 1. If $t=0$, then
$$
f(s,0;x)=\frac{|1+s|+|x+s|}{1+|s|+|x|}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(s,0;x)=1,
$$
so the supremum is (at least) 1 as well.

A similar substitution $x=-t/s$ works for the second supremum.